# R: use of ROI package

Tags: r, optimization, r-optimization

I am trying to use the R package ROI for a simple portfolio optimization problem.
I can get the results using the quadprog solver "manually", but I'd really like to understand how the ROI package works.
Unfortunately I run into an error, even though I am sticking to the provided example by Stefan Theussl at http://statmath.wu.ac.at/courses/optimization/Presentations/ROI-2011.pdf (slide 26,27)

Here is the code:

```
library(fPortfolio)  
library(ROI)

data(LPP2005.RET)  
lppData <- 100 * LPP2005.RET[, 1:6]
r <- mean(lppData)  
foo <- Q_objective(Q = cov(lppData), L = rep(0, ncol(lppData)))  
full_invest <- L_constraint(rep(1, ncol(lppData)), "==", 1)  
target_return <- L_constraint(apply(lppData, 2, mean), "==",r)
op <- OP(objective = foo, constraints = rbind(full_invest, target_return))   
sol <- ROI_solve(op, solver = "quadprog")
```

The error message I get is:

> Error in (dir == "<=") | (dir = q = "<") :    operations are possible
>   only for numeric, logical or complex types

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't know this package, but looks like you have a typo.  The second item in your "or" should probably be `dir == "<"` (where DID that "q" come from?) , or else both should use `=` .  My next guess is that one of your source variables is not of the required types, as the error message suggests.

Comment: I can't replicate this.  Did you call any other code that you haven't provided?  What does the call stack look like when you get the error? (Type `traceback()` after the error to see that.)

Comment: > traceback()
4: which((dir == "<=") | (dir = q = "<"))
3: .quadprog_solve_QP(Q = terms(objective(x))$Q, L = terms(objective(x))$L, 
       mat = constraints(x)$L, dir = constraints(x)$dir, rhs = constraints(x)$rhs, 
       max = x$maximum)
2: SOLVE(x, control)
1: ROI_solve(op, solver = "quadprog")

Comment: Carl, what do you mean by "my or"? The target_return constraint has to be an equality constraint, so I'm pretty sure there is nothing wrong with it. As far as typos go, I'm sure the only typo so far was OP, which is QP in the paper, but the function QP does not exist in the package... The whole thing is very confusing to me, but the fact that Richie can't replicate it, makes me think it must be something with the packages...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that there was a bug in the ROI quadprog plugin which has been fixed by the developer.

Comment: The current version (0.0-7) still has this problem.